# Transferring data from a form to master log, how do I always ensure the macro always goes to the next blank line

Tags: excel, macros

I have a form that the user completed **(Install Booking Spreadsheet V4)** the use completes this form and then transfers the data to a mater log **(Installer LOG 2.xlms)**

I have recorded a macro to copy, paste and transpose the data on to the log.  code below:

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Windows("Install Booking Spreadsheet v4.xlsm").Activate
    Range("B8:B14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Installer LOG 2.xlsm").Activate
        lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=True

Windows("Install Booking Spreadsheet v4.xlsm").Activate
    Range("B23").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Installer LOG 2.xlsm").Activate
        lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("H" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=True, Transpose:=True

Windows("Install Booking Spreadsheet v4.xlsm").Activate
    Range("B28").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Installer LOG 2.xlsm").Activate
        lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("I" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=True, Transpose:=True`
```

The Issue I have is on the (Install Booking Spreadsheet V4) dependent on the type of job the user may not fill in all of the various areas. When they then transfer this to the LOG, it leaves empty spaces on the log.  The next transfer of data may have additional areas of data and they jump to the previous empty cells. 
I thought that SkipBlanks-:=True would do the trick but no.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, use `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy` instead of `Selection.Copy`. This will copy only the cells with values

Comment: Hi,  The issue is not the copying of cells but the pasting of them onto the log **Installer LOG 2.xlms**. When the macro pastes it on to the log it leaves empty  cells depending on what data has been copied, then the next entry jumps into these empty cells.  What I want is that the empty cells are ignored and it pastes into the next line and doesn't jump up to the previous cell/line